# Vue.js cart quantity increment when id is already existing in cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, e-commerce

HI I am creating my own shopping cart and I am having a problem with quantity increments, whenever the id is already in the cart, so my question is how can I filter the id in cartList? so the id won't duplicate and instead increment the filtered id in the cart.

```
cartList: [],

productList:[],
cartadd: {
      id: 0,
      name: 0,
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
      image: ''
     }

    viewStorageCart () {
        if(localStorage.getItem('cartStorageList')) {
            this.cartList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartStorageList'))
        }
    },
    addStorageCart (product) {
        this.cartadd.id = product.id;
        this.cartadd.name = product.product_name;
        this.cartadd.price = product.product_price;
        this.cartadd.quantity = 1;
        this.cartadd.image = product.product_image;
        this.cartList.push(this.cartadd);
        this.cartadd = {}
        this.storeCart();
    }, 
    removeStorageCart (product) {
        this.cartList.splice(product, 1);
        this.storeCart();
    },
    storeCart() {
        let parsed = JSON.stringify(this.cartList);
        localStorage.setItem('cartLicartStorageListst', parsed)
        this.viewStorageCart();
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check in cartList array and increment qunatity if it exists

```
addStorageCart (product) {
 var findProduct = this.cartList.find(o => o.id === product.id)
 if(findProduct){
   findProduct.quantity +=1;
    return;
 }
this.cartadd.id = product.id;
this.cartadd.name = product.product_name;
this.cartadd.price = product.product_price;
this.cartadd.quantity = 1;
this.cartadd.image = product.product_image;
this.cartList.push(this.cartadd);
this.cartadd = {}
this.storeCart();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer just solve my problem thanks a lot !

Comment: how can i reduce the

Comment: On delete , find the product and decrement the quantity , if quantity has become 0 ,remove it from array.